# Ensuring query restrictions are honored during SaveChanges - Breeze security

Tags: security, breeze

Consider a typical Breeze controller that limits the results of a query to entities that the logged in user has access to. When the browser calls `SaveChanges`, does Breeze verify on the server that the entities reported as modified are from the original set?

To put it another way, does the `EFContextProvider` (in the case Entity Framework) keep track of entities that have been handed out, so it can check against malicious data passed to `SaveChanges`? Or does `BeforeSaveEntity` need to validate that the user has access to the changed entities?

Comment: Related, more general question on securing against malicious clients: [Securing Breeze on the server to prevent malicious updates to foreign keys](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17471823/145173)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** guard against malicious data in your *BeforeSaveEntity* or *BeforeSaveEntities* methods.

The idea that the EFContextProvider would keep track of entities that have already been handed out is probably something that we would NOT want to do because

- The EFContextProvider would no longer be stateless, which was a design goal to facilitate scaling.
- You would still need to guard against malicious data for "Added" entities in the BeforeXXX methods.
- It is actually a valid use case for some of our users to "modify" entities without having first queried them.